# colab_utils.annotate() - the execution doesn't complete

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've tried to copy locally the annotation example [notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/deepmac_colab.ipynb). When I tried to run it, the execution of a cell with colab_utils.annotate() doesn't complete:

```
image_path = 'models/research/object_detection/test_images/image3.jpg'
image = read_image(image_path)
display_image = resize_for_display(image)

boxes_list = []
colab_utils.annotate([display_image], boxes_list)
```

I've installed google.colab with conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-colab
```

Does anyone know what might be the cause for the command execution not being completed?